# Remove variables duplicates from data.table

Tags: r

I have data with over 6k columns. Each result has colums with data that are always the same.

```
   XCODE Age Sex ResultA Sex ResultB
1   X001  12   2       2       2       4
2   X002  23   2       4       2      66
3   X003  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
4   X004  32   1       1       1       3
5   X005  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
6   X001  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
7   X002  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
8   X003  33   1       8       1       6
9   X004  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
10  X005  55   2       8       2       8
```

I would like to remove duplicate e.g sex variable. Is there possibility of doing that with data.table?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match` if you need to check for equality of all values.

```
df[, unique(match(df, df)), with = F]

df2
#    XCODE Age Sex ResultA ResultB
# 1   X001  12   2       2       4
# 2   X002  23   2       4      66
# 3   X003  NA  NA      NA      NA
# 4   X004  32   1       1       3
# 5   X005  NA  NA      NA      NA
# 6   X001  NA  NA      NA      NA
# 7   X002  NA  NA      NA      NA
# 8   X003  33   1       8       6
# 9   X004  NA  NA      NA      NA
# 10  X005  55   2       8       8
```

Data used:

```
df <- fread('
   XCODE Age Sex ResultA Sex ResultB
1   X001  12   2       2       2       4
2   X002  23   2       4       2      66
3   X003  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
4   X004  32   1       1       1       3
5   X005  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
6   X001  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
7   X002  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
8   X003  33   1       8       1       6
9   X004  NA  NA      NA      NA      NA
10  X005  55   2       8       2       8
')[, -'V1']
```

Comment: okay, but I didnt mention that, there are some columns with same name which I would like to leave (contains core data). So how could I remove duplicates, in case where i know names of those columns which I want to remove?

Comment: This will leave columns with the same name, unless they have all the same values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 df[, unique(colnames(df))]
```

One caveat: it will delete all columns with duplicated names. In your case, it will delete `Sex` even if the two columns have the same name but different content.

Answer (score 1):

If you have duplicated columns with different names, you can transpose your dataframe, which allows you to use the `unique` function to solve your problem. Then you then transpose it back and set it back to dataframe (because it came a matrix when you transposed it).

```
df = data.frame(c = 1:5, a = c("A", "B","C","D","E"), b = 1:5)

df = t(df)
df = unique(df)
df = t(df)
df = data.frame(df)
```

Edit: like markus points out, this is probably not a good option if you have columns of multiples types because when t() coerces your dataframe to matrix it also coerces all your variables into the same type.

Comment: This might have the side effect that all numeric columns become characters or factros due to column `XCODE` in OP's case.

Comment: Hm, good point. It would require setting again your column types, and that would be bad.